# Run JavaScript file in NetBeans/Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, netbeans, node.js

Is there a way to run a JavaScript file directly in NetBeans or Eclipse?

I feel it's time consuming to fire up a terminal, browse to that file and run it with node all the time.

Answer (score 5):

Another NetBeans [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) plugin with a Node.js project type and npm integration (I am the author of it) is described in *[NetBeans Tools for Node.js](http://timboudreau.com/blog/read/NetBeans_Tools_for_Node_js)*

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can debug using Rhino in "Run As" without leaving Eclipse:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT/Debug
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/debug/

If you'd like to debug it remotely on a Node.js instance, you can use:
https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Using-Eclipse-as-Node-Applications-Debugger

If you'd like to remote debug a Chrome/Chromium browser:
http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/EclipseDebugger

The latter two options will use V8, which is Google's JS engine behind Chrome, which has also been implemented in Node.js. The first option will use Rhino, which is Mozilla's JS engine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run a JavaScript file directly from the NetBeans IDE with the [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) plugin:
[Download NodeJS plugin from netbeans.org](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=36653)

Comment: Well since Node.JS runs on windows i have made version 2.0 wich works on win machines, also can debug daemons like HTTP server implementations http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/36653/nodejs